# How do I attach an onchange() event into a dynamically created input text field?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to attach an `onchange()` listener into my `input` text field, inside my table like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("employees");

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";

var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2=row.insertCell(1);

cell1.innerHTML="<b>Name:</b>";
cell2.appendChild(input);

input.addEventListener("change",find_emp(input.value)); //not working
input.onchange=find_emp(input.value); //still not working
```

But the `onchange()` event  is not working. What do I do in order to make it work?

Comment: `find_emp(input.value)` ---> `() => find_emp(input.value)` - you need to pass a function to the `addEventListener`; you are passing the result of calling the `find_emp` function.

Comment: Thank you its working now, can you please help me with one more thing? I am also using  `input.addEventListener("keyup",() => force_upper(input.value))`, which too is not working. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an arrow function for both events `change` and `keyup` like:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("employees");

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";

var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2=row.insertCell(1);

cell1.innerHTML="<b>Name:</b>";
cell2.appendChild(input);

input.addEventListener("change",() => console.log("from change", input.value)); 
input.addEventListener("keyup",() => console.log("from keyup", input.value));
```

```html
<table id="employees" />
```